# Reviewboard does not recognize .diff file mercurial

Tags: mercurial, review-board

Before committing I export my code changes in mercurial like
`hg diff -r tip > d.diff` or `hg export -o d.diff` It creates a nice `.diff` When I upload this to [review board](https://www.reviewboard.org/) it returns empty diff file.

File is not empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: I'm still using `hg diff` method, I'll check it and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow you are using (manual hg diff + diff file upload via web browser) is painful and lacks flexibility. When an error occurs, reviewboard is not very helpful in explaining what is going on (to use an euphemism :-).

I suggest two different approaches, which often work out of the box. They are in order of preference from my point of view (that is, I prefer option 1 to option 2).

1. Use the [hgreviewboard](https://bitbucket.org/ccaughie/hgreviewboard/wiki/Home) extension. This allows to stay in hg for all reviewboard operations: `hg postreview ...` will do the diff and upload to reviewboard. `hg help postreview` will explain all the options and the advanced usage.
2. Use the [post-review](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/users/tools/post-review) script, provided by reviewboard.org. This approach also allows to avoid the manual steps of the browser upload. The link above has full documentation.